# .css() won't get applied after a delay

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I wanted to change the background-color on a div dinamically using jQuery's `css()` and it worked, but then I tried to add some delay to it, and for some reason it stopped working. What am I missing? Here's an MVC of it:

HTML:

```
<div id="nodelay"></div>
<div id="delay"></div>
```

JS:

```
$("#nodelay").hover(function() {
       $(this).css("background-color", 'gray');
     });

$("#delay").hover(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $(this).css("background-color", 'gray');
    }, 500);
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/8eabfa2t/1/

Comment: Just incase you were actually unaware, you don't need to use JS to change the CSS of an element when hovered. You can just do `#nodelay:hover { ... }` in your stylesheet. EDIT: just noticed this is an old question, but I can't delete this comment. Meh.

Comment: Yes, thank you. This is a simplified example to demonstrate the issue. I was planning for more complex actions on that element's hover.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout#The_this_problem):

> **The "`this`" problem**
>
> Code executed by `setTimeout()` is **called from a separate execution context to the function from which `setTimeout` was called**. The usual rules for setting the `this` keyword for the called function apply, and if you have not set this in the call or with `bind`, **it will default to the global (or `window`) object** in non–strict mode, or be undefined in strict mode. It will not be the same as the this value for the function that called `setTimeout`. (Emphasis mine)

Since functions passed to `setTimeout` are executed in a different context, `this` is not bound. That would mean `this` actually refers to `window` (or `undefined` in strict mode). You are essentially doing `$(window).css(...)` which is not intended.

To combat this, you may use [`Function.prototype.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to bind `this` context as mentioned above. From the documentation:

> The `bind()` method creates a new function that, when called, has its `this` keyword set to the provided value

Since `this` outside of the `setTimeout` function is the element (as jQuery does this for you via explicit `this` binding like we're doing here), using `$(this)` will refer to the `#delay` element:

```js
$("#nodelay").hover(function() {
  $(this).css("background-color", 'gray');
});

$("#delay").hover(function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $("#delay").css("background-color", 'gray');
  }.bind(this), 500);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="nodelay">Test</div>
<div id="delay">Test</div>
```

You can alternatively, as mentioned, capture `this` before you enter the anonymous function, or explicitly mention the element in the selector. If you're using ES6, another way to do this is to use [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), which do not bind their own `this`, referring to that of the enclosing context.

Comment: As Andrew and yezzz point out, it's due to the scope of $(this). The following jsfiddle shows how you can just capture the element pointed to by $(this) before assigning the setTimeout funciton. https://jsfiddle.net/wp22e68z/

Answer (score 3):

This is due to the scope of `this` in the function after the delay. There are a lot of ways to get passed this, and everyone has their preference. My preferred method is using the `Function.prototype.bind()` method. It binds the function's `this` reference to whatever you pass it as the first object.

The reason this works is hard for me to explain (it makes a lot of sense in my head), but the easiest way I can say it is that the `this` being passed to `.bind()` is the same `this` you would call from the `.hover()` call.

```js
$("#nodelay").hover(function() {
  $(this).css("background-color", 'gray');
});

$("#delay").hover(function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $(this).css("background-color", 'gray');
  }.bind(this), 500);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="nodelay">t</div>
<div id="delay">t</div>
```

Another way that people do it is by declaring a variable outside of the function where the `this` call is being messed up. Because of how scope in Javascript works, any functions declared after that variable can access it.

```js
$("#nodelay").hover(function() {
  $(this).css("background-color", 'gray');
});

$("#delay").hover(function() {
  var self = this;
  setTimeout(function() {
    $(self).css("background-color", 'gray');
  }, 500);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="nodelay">t</div>
<div id="delay">t</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

helpfule reading: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout#The_this_problem
(if that link doesn't take you right to the 'the "this" problem, search for it on the page)

Does this work for you:

```
$("#delay").hover(function() {
    var target = $(this);
   setTimeout(function() {
     target.css("background-color", 'gray');
   }, 500);
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

That's not due to timeout, but related to the scope of `this`.

https://jsfiddle.net/8eabfa2t/4/

Answer (score 0):

Great answers from others. Since everyone else pointed out problem with use of 'this' context, I won't bother to explain it more. However if I may, I would like to introduce you to an alternative and very useful jQuery [$.proxy()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/) function. It allows you to set the context of your choice. First argument to proxy function is a function to be executed. Second argument is the context, then what ever the argument you need to parse to the function. Try the example below

```js
$("#nodelay").hover(function() {
       $(this).css("background-color", 'gray');
     });

$("#delay").hover(function() {
    setTimeout($.proxy(function() {
        $(this).css("background-color", 'gray');
    }, this) , 500);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="nodelay">t</div>
<div id="delay">t</div>
```